# %a for days in the difference of two date formates

Tags: php

In the following snap, `%a` is meant for the amount in days, but I could not find it mentioned in the documentation of PHP, neither within `DateTime` nor `DateInterval` classes.
Indeed `%h`, `%i` and `%s` are all mentioned in the documentation of `date()` which parameters are accepted by `format()`, among those in `date()` is indeed `a`, but it means only *am* or *pm*, not the amount of days.
So where did `%a` comes from?

The snap:

```
$span = $d1->diff($today);
echo "{$span->format("%a %h %i %s")} days"
```

Question was answered by Nick comments below.. All is good. Thank you Nick.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Thank you very much. The question is done here.